# Execute Mysql query in php

Tags: php, sql

I'm sure I'm getting the vaue of `$bn` and `$answer` on my page now I just want to insert the value in the column answer value `$answer` where qid is `$bn`.

```
<?php

$answer = $_POST['one'];
$an = $_POST['two'];
$bn = $an - 1;
echo "$bn";
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pankaj') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('quiz', $con) or die(mysql_error());
$q = "INSERT INTO question(uanswer) VALUE '" . $answer . "' where qid='" . $bn . "'";
$rq = mysql_query($q, $con);
if (!$rq) {
    echo " the sql query faiiled to work ";
} else {
    echo "the query executed sucessfully";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use Update Insert not support where condition.

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT` statement does not support `WHERE` clause.

[`Syntax on how to write an INSERT statement.`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

Comment: this is weired,this is second time I am facing this

Comment: @ Shankar Damodaran but its not letting me do urs,but why this is happening?is it by some moderators?

Comment: @Abhishek, Doesn't matter.

Comment: Why did you delete this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556648/php-regexp-extract-last-part-of-string#22556740

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, Because it didn't get any attention ..moreover that solution was not `regex` based.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: I was about to upvote it! The fact that it is not a regex based solution is not really a problem. Most people believes that a regex based solution is always the fastest way.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, Undeleted it mate.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to update the database or insert?
`INSERT` will not work with `WHERE` clause.