# PHP regexp; extract last part of string

Tags: php, regex

A column in my spreadsheet contains data like this:

```
5020203010101/FIS/CASH FUND/SBG091241212
```

I need to extract the last part of string after forwward slash (/) i.e; **SBG091241212**

I tried the following regular expression but it does not seem to work:

```
\/.*$
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a matching group using brackets in order to extract content.

```
preg_match("/\/([^\/]+)$/", "5020203010101/FIS/CASH FUND/SBG091241212", $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: This is the best answer, other people used code other than regular expression to get correct results.

Comment: @asim-ishaq: Yes, however, keep in mind that the regex way can be slower than the use of build-in functions.

Comment: Perfectly good answer, though it's not essential to use sub-matches. A look-behind would also suffice.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
'/(?<=\/)[^\/]*$/'
```

The reason your current REGEXP is failing is because your `.*` directive matches slashes too, so it anchors to the first slash and gives you everything after it (FIS/CASH FUND/SBG091241212).

Comment: this also doesn't work `http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%3F%3C%3D\%2F%29[^\%2F]*%24&input=5020203010101%2FFIS%2FCASH%20FUND%2FSBG091241212`

Comment: @php_nub_qq: It's because you use a tester for javascript regexes (that doesn't support lookbehind assertions). Try with http://regex101.com and you will see that it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `substr()` with `strrpos()` as a look behind.

```
echo substr($str,strrpos($str,'/')+1); //"prints" SBG091241212
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/124249)

Comment: TBH regex gurus don't need to know abt it though ;)

Comment: Thanks, but if you want to see real gurus, you can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039670/vertical-regex-matching-in-an-ascii-image

Comment: I just lost myself ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this without reg ex:

```
<?php

echo end(explode('/', '5020203010101/FIS/CASH FUND/SBG091241212'));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this will do a positive lookbehind and match upto a value which does not contain a slash

like this

```
[^\/]*?(?<=[^\/])$
```

this will only highlight the match . i.e. the last part of the url

demo here : **http://regex101.com/r/pF8pS2**

Answer (score 0):

You can 'explode' the string:

```
$temp = explode('/',$input);
if (!empty($temp)){
    $myString = $temp[count($temp)-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
$string = '5020203010101/FIS/CASH FUND/SBG091241212';
echo basename($string);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php